# Use XPath to generate XML file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xhtml

I have an assignment that I don't understand how to solve. Basically I have three XML files with data. They all have the same structure just different information. From these files I only want to use certain elements. This I know how to do using an XSLT-file. However, the assignment tells me to use XPath to extract data from these three XML-files and then transform them into a new XML-file that includes the chosen data from all the three files. After this I'm supposed to transform my XML-file into XHTML using a XSLT-file.

Right now I have a working XSLT-file transforming data from one of the original XML-files into XHTML.

The problem is that I don't understand how I'm supposed to use XPath to generate a new XML from the three original XML-files as specified in the assignment.

Comment: You could use the `document` function to allow your XSLT to access documents other than the main one you are processing. For example `<xsl:value-of select="document('file2.xml')/data/record[@id='2']/name" />`. If you can't get it to work, you will really need to edit your question to show samples of your XML files and the output you need. Thank you!

Comment: @TimC I understand what you mean. However, my question is not how I can access multiple XML-files but how to generate a new XML-file from already existing XML-files using XPath.

Comment: XSLT generates new XML or HTML or XHTML, XPath never generates new XML, it only selects existing nodes in XML documents. If you know how to process one XML file with XSLT then you can also process three of them if needed to create a new one: `<xsl:template match="/*"><xsl:copy><xsl:copy-of select="node() | document('file2.xml')/*/node() | document('file3.xml')/*/node()"/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.